# Write physical table to csv file

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, io

I was wondering if anyone knows how to write an actual table/grid to a csv file....i dont mean the content of the table/grid, i mean the actual grid lines etc etc, headers, axis.....

Thanks greatly in advance.

U.

Comment: How would you like to display these graphical elements? As ASCII characters?

Comment: Can you explain further what your requirement is? Also why do you need to store the grid lines, etc?

Comment: Create a standard grid in word, headers and random contents with random amounts of rows and columns.

I want this exact grid to be created in code (doesnt matter what software design is put towards this), but how do you write the entire table, including the gridlines etc to a csv/text file. What objects do you use for this creation and how this is written to a file.

Comment: A CSV file is a plain text file!

Comment: I got that before.....but god knows how things can be done!
Ok fair enough, so what file type do you suggest for me to write an actual physical grid...and what would be used to build such a grid?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible at all to write a physical grid to any type of file....i was trying xmlwriter and xamlwriters there now and both output the text representation of the xaml code....and i def dont want to create the grid using ASCII characters.....

Comment: So you're trying to "write" the images that represent gridlines to a text file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MPritch has said the CSV format is plain text and as such seems unsuitable to your needs. If you have a grid object that you're happy with you can probably serialise it to disk using one of the formatters (eg BinaryFormatter) or the XmlSerialiser.

Comment: Will this end up providing me with a file that contains the grid contents? Or will this actually serialize the lines as well, and actual write the grid to the file?

Thanks.

Comment: @urema: it should keep any of the properties you set on the grid. it's very simple code `binaryFormatter.Serialize(gridObject);` - give it a try.

Comment: Ill give this a try anyway for my own knowledge....however I have got an updated requirement stating that this needs to be written through a XPSDocument....so all is good.

Thanks for your help!